# Why am I getting run-time error? The code is still giving me the correct output

Tags: c, runtime-error

Why am I getting run-time error when running this code?
Here's a Test Input Case:

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long int s[999999];
// Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
int main()
{
    int n,m,i;
    long int a,b,val,cval;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    for(;m>0;m--)
    {
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&val);
        s[a-1]+=val;
        if(b!=n)
            s[b]-=val;
    }
    val=s[0];
    cval=s[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        cval+=s[i];
        if(val<cval)
            val=cval;
    }
    printf("%ld",val);
    return val;
}
```

Expected and actual results match but compiler giving run-time error.

Comment: Compilers don't give run-time errors.  When you run the program, what is the error you get?

Comment: Is the problem simply that your program is exiting with `return val;` and `val` is not zero (it's 200 for the test data), so the exit status is treated as an error status?  I've run the code, and I don't see anything else to cause trouble.

Comment: OP, Please use `gdb` to find where its crashing. Do share `backtrace` if you're able to get it.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan laffer that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement of your application should usually return `EXIT_SUCCESS` (0) or `EXIT_FAILURE` (1).

You return a very positive value - which is means for the shell that this was an error. Just change the return value to "0" or `EXIT_SUCCESS` to remove that "run time error".

See also:
[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)